# How to call script with timestamps relative to now, on Solaris?

Tags: shell-script, solaris, timestamps

We have List Error shell script, but I run it manually daily. I want to run the script via `crontab` automatically.

My script :

```shell
#!/bin/sh
ent programe -a$1 -b$2 -c$3 -d$4 -tTE -oListErrorTE.txt
grep " ERR1" ListErrorTE.txt
grep " ERR2" ListErrorTE.txt
```

Explanation:

```
$1 = date start >> 20230914
$2 = time start >> 000100
$3 = date end >> 20230914
$5 = time end >> 163000
```

I want to replace the parameter date time start older than 2 hours and replace the end date time with the current date time?

Comment: We would need to know more, as the `date` command can vary. Please add to your question (a) The Solaris version, and (b) the output from `date; date -d 'now - 2 hours' '+%Y%m%d %H%M%S'`. That command will suggest how you might edit your script to obtain the new values it requires.

Answer (score 3):

Your script takes four arguments on its command line that correspond to a start date and time, and an end date and time, and you appear to want to call your script without specifying specific arguments.  Instead you want the start date and time to be "two hours ago" and the end date and time to be "now".

Assuming that your Solaris system has GNU `date` installed (the utility [is listed](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37839/date-1g.html) in the official Solaris manual, so it can at least be made available by an administrator), then you may use this to calculate the values of the four arguments like this:

```bash
/some/path/yourscript \
    "$(date -d '2 hours ago' +%Y%m%d)" \
    "$(date -d '2 hours ago' +%H%M%S)" \
    "$(date +%Y%m%d)" \
    "$(date +%H%M%S)"
```

If this command was run on 2023-09-14, at 09:44:03, your script would be called with the four arguments `20230914`, `074403`, `20230914`, and `094403`.

The four command substitutions use GNU `date` to calculate and return the four date and timestamps needed.

If you are afraid that some of the four invocations of `date` are on different sides of a second, minute, hour, or day, etc., then first get the Unix timestamp for "now" and use `date` with an offset to that to get the needed date and timestamps:

```bash
now=$(date +%s)

offset=$(( -2*60*60 ))    # -2h in seconds

/some/path/yourscript \
    "$(date -d "@$(( now + offset ))" +%Y%m%d )" \
    "$(date -d "@$(( now + offset ))" +%H%M%S )" \
    "$(date -d "@$now" +%Y%m%d )" \
    "$(date -d "@$now" +%H%M%S )"
```

Without GNU `date`, but with a reasonably up-to-date release of `bash` (version 4.2 or later, which should be available on Solaris according to [the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37839/bash-1.html)):

```bash
printf -v now '%(%s)T' -1

offset=$(( -2*60*60 ))    # -2h in seconds

/some/path/yourscript \
    "$( printf '%(%Y%m%d)T' "$(( now + offset ))" )" \
    "$( printf '%(%H%M%S)T' "$(( now + offset ))" )" \
    "$( printf '%(%Y%m%d)T' "$now" )" \
    "$( printf '%(%H%M%S)T' "$now" )"
```

This uses the special date formatting capabilities of the built-in `printf` utility in `bash` in an analogous way to the previous code snippet.  First, it calculates the Unix timestamp for "now" (storing that in the shell variable `now`) and then uses that to calculate the offset for "two hours ago" and outputs the formatted date and timestamps as arguments to your script.

For your cron job, you would take one of these pieces of code and schedule that. It would probably make the most sense to put the code in a separate script, `yourscript-runner`, that is scheduled with cron, rather than trying to insert a very long command in the crontab file directly, partly because the `%` character is special in cron schedules and has to be escaped, and partly because that would also give you a separate script for running the tasks manually, would you want to do so.

```
0 0 * * * /some/path/yourscript-runner
```

(The above cron schedule would trigger every midnight.)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible (with a little lateral thinking) to do this on a standard Solaris system (without GNU date).

Set up a cron job to run the script every two hours.

On entry, the script runs `date` and saves the current date and time as the "start" parameters.

It then sleeps for 7200 seconds.

When the sleep expires, it runs `date` again, and saves the now current date and time as the "end" parameters.

You now have the four values you need to extract the data for the previous two hours. You can even use the end start and date as part of the filename for the results.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 11, Solaris' `/bin/sh` is actually `ksh93` whose `printf` builtin can do advanced date manipulation and formatting (a lot more advanced than GNU `date` as a matter of fact).

I would still use `#! /bin/ksh93 -` instead of `#! /bin/sh -` to make it clear that it's not standard `sh` syntax but ksh93 one (like I would not use bashism in a `#! /bin/sh -` script on systems where `sh` is bash):

```
#! /bin/ksh93 -
eval "${
  printf '
    ent programe %(-a%Y%m%d -b%H%M%S)T %(-c%Y%m%d -d%H%M%S)T -tTE -oListErrorTE.txt
  ' '2 hours ago' now
}"
grep ' ERR1' ListErrorTE.txt
grep ' ERR2' ListErrorTE.txt
```